# How to solve this recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n/2) +O(n\log n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

**Problem:** Inspiring by the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159720/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-tn-2tn-2-n-log-n), I wonder how to solve the recurrence
$$ T(n) = 2T(n/2) +\mathcal{O}(n\log n).$$

I had just thought about this question already when I saw the above post. I hope everyone can give me some ideas about this extension version.

Comment: How is this different from the question you linked? The $O$ on the $n\log n$? It doesn't change the answer, and you should be easily able to fix the proof for this case

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, we can estimate the upper bound of T(n) as $O(n\log{n})$ but how can we estimate the lower bound that deduces the same result $\Theta(n\log^2n)$.

Comment: You can't get a lower bound, because $1=O(n\log n)$, so $T(n) = \Theta(n)$ is also a possible solution